# Looking for older conducting train tracks

Tags: shopping, trains, vintage, tracks, 9v

I have an old 9V era (1991-2006) train set that has conducting tracks. Is there a place that I can buy conducting tracks? Obviously I have trolled eBay, Amazon and internet without success.
I can buy unconnected tracks and glue aluminum foil on the tracks for conduction. Will it work ?

Any help in securing more conducted tracks or guidance re: modifying new tracks will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: A place to look is [Brick link](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/search.page?q=track%209v#T=P)

Comment: Pretty sure the comment from @Dan1138 is the actual answer. For example here are all of the short curved track lots available https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3241#T=S&C=9&O={%22color%22:9,%22iconly%22:0}

Comment: From 2012 to 2015 I bought them in packs off eBay, i.e. auctions with ~100 used tracks. My maximum was always 3.50 € per straight part, 1.00 € for curves, 10.00 € for switches, 20.00 € for crosses. Based on the quality I got it was always worth the money. Cleaned them thru the years throughly, tho.

Comment: I've 1 you can have, curved.

Answer (score 6):

Such place indeed exist and it is called [Bricklink](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/main.page), a website dedicated to trading LEGO items. It has extensive history and great catalog of LEGO items found on the internet. Prices and quality are, usually, far better than you would find on eBay. And as an extra bonus, there are sellers from all over the world, so you are not limited to you own region.

As Dan noted in the comments Bricklink catalog contain [all types of 9V train tracks](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogList.asp?pg=1&catString=128&catType=P&v=1) you are interested in for sale both in Dark Gray (older) and Dark Bluish Gray (newer) colors.

**Edit.** Upon further investigation decided to clarify situation in terms of custom tracks. While there are few 3rd party companies producing LEGO-compatible non-9V train tracks there aren't as much options with 9V ones. ME-Models used to produced some, but the company is gone now. FxBricks has shared their plans to introduce 9V tracks at some point the future.

Comment: Thanks guys the reply were very helpful . I found what I was looking for.

Comment: In the context of conducting tracks: can you at least name (if not link) to the companies? There was one once, but it ceased to exist years ago. And didn't apply to "better geometry options", too.

Comment: I don't want any of it, but I have heard about them from fellow LEGO-fans that are not as purist and bigger train fans, but some brands are ME models and bricktrack.

Comment: Thanks, that was [ME Models](https://web.archive.org/web/20170614104242/http://www.me-models.com/store/) (conducted) and is [BrickTracks](https://www.bricktracks.com/products) (non-conducted).